# XCode 6.1 freezes/is slow

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have the following random problems with XCode 6.1.1. I have OSX 10.10.1 on a MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2014 (16gb RAM, without Nvidia Graphics).

The rest of the machine seem to work just fine.

- The editor and interface builder freeze randomly (see picture below)
- The interface is always very slow at zooming. It takes up to 5 seconds until the interface builder applied the pinch-to-zoom.
- Sometimes pinch-to-zoom and/or scrolling stop to work at all within whole XCode.

I have to restart XCode up three times in a row until the issue is temporarely solved (not the pinch to zoom issue, this always sucks).

This is how the editor looks like when the editor freezes (same applies to the interface builder):
[image]